# Objects not being saved correctly in grails

Tags: grails

I have an error which only happens when I call the code from an external source.

I am getting a stack overflow exception due to the created object not getting saved, meaning I cannot create a link between objects.

my code is as follows:

```
private addToJob (Manufacture m, Job j, int count = 0){
    if(m.id)
        j.addToManufactures(m)
    else{
        sleep(1000)
        m.save(flush:true,failOnError:true)
        addToJob(m,j,count++);
    }
    if(count >= 10)
        throw new Exception("missing ID")
}
```

Does anyone know what using a flush on save is not giving the Manufacture object an id?
I am using MySql.

Comment: How do `Manufacture` and `Job` look in relation to each other within their domain classes?

Answer (score 0):

the domain needs both HasMany and BelongsTo 
I was missing the BelongsTo